# Adding integers to strings in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Recently I have been informed that it is possible to concatenate integers (and other types) to string and vice versa, i.e.

```
// x == "1234"
// y == "7890"
string x = "123" + 4;
string y = 7 + "890";
```

For some reason I didn't think this kind of thing was allowed, so I have always been using (since .NET 2) the form:

```
// x == "1234"
// y == "7890"
string x = "123" + 4.ToString();
string y = 7.ToString() + "890";
```

where the integers are converted to strings.  Has the former version always been available, and I've missed it, or is it something that is new to C# 4 (which is what I am using now)?

Comment: It's just type conversion in action, definitely around in earlier versions.  You'll likely find that both compile into the same MSIL form.

Comment: Oh, yes, looking back at coding standards docs I see that I was encouraged to be explicit in my code to make it more readable.  'var x = value + 10' could be anything, for example, while 'string x = value + 10.ToString()' leaves little to the imagination.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has always been there. The `+` is equivalent to `string.Concat()` if at least one of the operands is a string. `string.Concat()` has an overload that takes an `object` instance. Internally it will call the object's `ToString()` method before concatenating.

Found the relevant section in the C# spec - section 7.7.4 Addition operator:

> **String concatenation**:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string. If an operand of string concatenation is
>   null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string
>   argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the
>   virtual ToString method inherited from type object. If ToString
>   returns null, an empty string is substituted.

Comment: Pretty sure it has some null checking though, so it's not entirely equivalent to just calling .ToString on the other object (if that object is nullable).

Comment: This. What "+" means is context-dependent based on the left-hand value. If it's numeric, it's mathematic addition. If it's a string, it's concatenation. If it's a user-defined type, the operator method will define the expected type(s) of the RValue, and the behavior of the operator given an expected RValue type.

Comment: If 7 is on left side of the "+" it should call the + operator on an integer. Seems they support strings there. MSDN writes "        Console.WriteLine(5.0 + "5"); // string concatenation
        // note automatic conversion from double to string" << that comment is interesting

Answer (score 3):

Of course, the best answer is to use some form of:

```
String.Format("{0},{1}", "123", 4);
```

Comment: Why exactly this is the best?!

Comment: I agree (with being more explicit, though your form ins't the same), I don't think just 'adding' strings and integers is the best plan, especially when you get code like 'var x = value + 10'

Comment: Try using the String.Concat method at least if you want the integer 1234 + "10" it won't end up being 1244 does this make sense