# Specified cast is not valid - System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I've read many of similar questions and tried several different things, but I do not understand why this is not working. The column that is being summed is of the int type. I have tried casting to uint and int32. I appreciate direction. Thank you.

```
        int i = 1;
        int total=0;
        while (i < 7)
        {

            string conString = @"Data Source=UATDB2\sqleuat;Initial Catalog=CVNee;User ID=appuser;Integrated Security=true";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL2 WHERE TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL2.TRANS_TYPE =" + i + "AND TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL2.HOH_UPI = '185292000'";

           int amt = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            //amt = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (i == 1)
            {
                total = total + amt;
            }

            if (i == 2)
            {
                total = total - amt;
            }

            if (i == 3)
            {
                total = total - amt;
            }

            if (i == 4)
            {
                total = total + amt;
            }

            if (i == 5)
            {
                total = total + amt;
            }

            if (i == 6)
            {
                total = total + amt;
            }

            connection.Close();
            ViewBag.TotalBalance = total;

            i++;
        }
```

Comment: If the SUM returns null, I think you'll get such error.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that too. I'm now using Convert.ToInt32 and I'm getting a more detailed exception. What would be the best way to handle the potential null?

Comment: And as nearly always with SQL related questions: Don't create queries using string concatenation but use parametrized queries as they will prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The illegal cast exception occurs, when `ExecuteScalar` returns `null`. You could either check if the result is `null` before converting to `int`,

```
 object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 int result = o == null ? 0 : (int)o;
```

or you could use a nullable int `int?` which can also be checked if it has a value

```
 int? result = (int?)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if (!result.HasValue) result = 0;
```

or you could adjust your query to return `0` even if no matching rows are found. The TSQL function `COALESCE`checks if the first parameter is `NULL`, if no it returns the value, if yes, it returns the value of the second parameter.

```
 string query = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(AMOUNT),0) FROM TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL2 WHERE TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL2.TRANS_TYPE =" + i + "AND TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL2.HOH_UPI = '185292000'";
```

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` will return `null` if the result set is absolutely empty, or `DBNull`, if there are rows but there is nothing to sum up. In your code you do not handle the case of DBNull. I must admit, my answer - vice versa - did not cover the `null` :-) So - you and me together - are giving the rigth answer

Answer (score 1):

#### according to your comment

If you call `ExecuteScalar`, you might get `null` or `DBNull` in return, and you should check both. You can first fill it into a variable of type `object`, then check for `DBNull.Value` and `null` and react on this:

```
int amt=0;
object amtUnchecked = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(amtUnchecked != DBNull.Value && amtUnchecked!=null)
    amt=(int)amtUnchecked;
```

Or you change the `SELECT` to return a sure zero: `SELECT ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT),0) ...`

Comment: The code works when I make sure the sum query does not return a null value. The issue is in being able to control the null value that is returned when casting amt to int. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's wrong, I'm not sure, whether `ToString()` is implicily called or if the `+` operator is overloaded for `String + int`

Comment: @derpirscher, yes,you're right, [found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418815/adding-integers-to-strings-in-c-sharp). I will delete this part from my answer...

Comment: @Shnugo I tried using ISNULL like you answered: http://pastebin.com/Wbvpekt4 but I'm getting an excetion saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'". Thanks for the help!

Comment: @vmil, your syntax is not correct: The `ISNULL()` function needs a second parameter (the value in case of `NULL`) and a closing paranthesis: `ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT),0) FROM...`

Comment: I appreciate the help -- my mistake with the syntax.