# Passing value inside Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, console.writeline

Here is a piece of code am working on

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number to find factorial : ");
        var fac = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var res = 1;
        for (var i = fac; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            res = res * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count of " + fac + " is : " + res);
    }
}
```

I want to add the user entered input `fac` in result. Here am using `Console.WriteLine("Count of " + fac + " is : " + res);` to display the output in my console.

I tried something like

```
Console.WriteLine("Count of {0} is : {1} ", fac, res);
```

Is there a better way to do this or this is just fine..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution would be to use [string interpolation](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Count of {fac} is : {res}");
```

Comment: So when we use `$` before the string it will consider the things inside flower brackets as variables..

Comment: yup pretty much. I have appended a link for further explanation.

Comment: Bear in mind, this is C#6 feature, so by default, it is available since VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine("Count of {0} is : {1} ", fac, res);` is an [overload of `Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports format string.

If you need to fill string template (e.g. "Count of {0} is : {1} ") with values (e.g fac, res) you can also use string interpolation (.net 4.6) or [`String.Format` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) with overloads which also makes easier to fill template with repeated values (e.g. `String.Format("{0}-{1} {0}-{1} {2}", 1,2,3);`)

```
string s = String.Format("Count of {0} is : {1} ", fac, res);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Good to know :).. Thanks!! Much appropriated

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid the use of the addition operator because it can lead to unexpected results; e.g.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
Console.WriteLine("hello world " + a + b);
//hello world 12
Console.WriteLine(a + b + " hello world");
//3 hello world
```

The two lines look as if they'd produce similar output, only one beginning `hello world` & the other ending with that.  However, the numeric component of the string is 12 in the first example (`"1" + "2"`), whilst it's 3 in the second (`1 + 2`).

**[@Aominè's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247694/361842)'s best, since that's very clearly readable.**
You can also apply formatting with this technique; i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine("hello world {a:0.00} {b}");
//hello world 1.00 2
```

NB: The option to apply formatting is also available with numeric placeholders:

```
Console.WriteLine("hello world {0} {1:0.00}", a, b);
//hello world 1 2.00
```

The time when it makes sense to use numeric placeholders over interpolation is if you need to define your format before you define the variables.  e.g.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    const string MyStringFormat = "hello {0} world {1}";    
    public static string WriteMessage(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyStringFormat, a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unbelievable that `Console.WriteLine(a + b + " hello world");` compiles (it does). How does that even work? If you try and add a string to an int it would fail usually, so what's going on here?

Comment: @Mardoxx; agreed that it seems unexpected.  There's a great explanation of what's going on, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9418859/361842.

Comment: Anyone care to see what VB.NET's & (concatenate) operator would compile to?  Surprised can't force equivalent in C#.